# After firebase.auth().signOut() when I am trying to login again without signing up, it doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am unable to login after firebase.auth().signOut(). If I do sign up again then it works. But exiting user can not sign in. What should I do?

LogOut:

```
private void logout() {
    session.setLoggedin(false);
    mAuth.signOut();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

LogIn:

```
private void LogIn() {
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.child("+880" + mobile).exists() && dataSnapshot.child("+880" + mobile).child("password").getValue().equals(userPassword) ) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                session.setLoggedin(true);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User or Password doesn't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182917/firebase-how-to-do-a-phone-number-authentication-after-the-user-has-been-regist   May be this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Firebase Authentication to handle your login method. The onDataChange method under the addValueEventListener only triggers when a particular data changes in your Firebase Database. Therefore, if nothing changes in your database, the code inside onDataChange will never be executed.

Here is a simple example of how to sign in users with Firebase Authentication:

```
private void login(String email, String password) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //If login is successful do something here
                    } else {
                        //If login is not successful do something here
                    }
                }
             });
}
```

Make sure to register your users with Firebase Authentication when they sign up so you can sign them in using Firebase Authentication. As I can see that you sign out your users with Firebase Authentication method, I assume you have signed them up with Firebase Authentication as well? Therefore, try to access the users' password from your authentication side, not from the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to signInWith Phone & Password ? Because I have used Phone Authentication. Right now I am having a problem of signing in of existed users.

Comment: Yes you can pass your PhoneAuthCredential instead of email and password to your login method. Also, instead of mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword, you should use mAuth.signInWithCredential, which takes a parameter of your credential.

Don't forget that you have to verify the users' phone numbers first before they can actually sign in with their phone numbers.

Comment: So do I have to store the varification ID and code?
PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);

article https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth