# Firebase: How to do a phone number authentication after the user has been registered?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I know I can use email verification, or phone number verification, but what I want to do is a phone number verification after the user has registered or logged in. How do you connect this these two authentication methods. Finally, is there a function in Firebase to check if the user is verified by phone number or not? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use the APi provided by firebase to verify the number even if the user is authenticated. According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth?hl=pt-br) , the authentication happens only when the user receives the confirmation code and generates a `PhoneAuthCredential`. If you just want to vrify the phone you can simply provide a custom reaction to the callback `onVerificationCompleted`.

Normally you set up the provider:

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber,        
        60,                 
        TimeUnit.SECONDS,   
        this,               
        mCallbacks);
```

And you implement a series of callbacks.

```
mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        //No need to authenticate again, just react to verified number
        //signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

        if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

        } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                           PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {

        mVerificationId = verificationId;
        mResendToken = token;

    }
};
```

According to your second question about to verify how the user is signed in you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619628/how-to-determine-if-a-firebase-user-is-signed-in-using-facebook-authentication/38619970#38619970) to see how to check the firebase user authentication providers.

When a user is logged in you can get its phone number (if there is any) by calling:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String number = user.getPhoneNumber();
```

Comment: Wow, you are being more than helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help :)